# Python SQL syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

Im trying to run a python script on my raspberry pi, in order to store the data that I receive from the gps receiver into a sql table. While Im executing this script I'm getting an error on this part of the code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO gps (n_lat, w_long, date_time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" % (north, west, t,)
print sql
cur.execute(sql)
print "Rows inserted: %s" % cur.rowcount
con.commit()
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gps.py", line 48, in <module>
  cur.execute(sql)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
  self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':01:16)' at line 1")
```

I don't really understand where is the problem, Have you got any ideas why whiz error occurs ?

Comment: Don't you need single quotes around %s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not escape your input values. For numbers this is optional, but datetime might not be a number.

However, you should **always** escape input values for your database. The keyword here is **prepared statements**. Instead of parsing your input arguments into the string with pythons `%` operater, you should use the argument list of `cursor.execute`.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO gps (n_lat, w_long, date_time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
print sql
cur.execute(sql, (north, west, t,))
print "Rows inserted: %s" % cur.rowcount
con.commit()
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Now the function `execute` will make sure, that all special characters are escaped. E.g. one of your input values might contain a single quote or similar. Using python's string parsing, this would result in something like:

```
"INSERT INTO gps (n_lat, w_long, date_time) VALUES ('123', '123', '1234'321')"
```

In best case this would result in a database error, in worst case somebody could manipulate your database with his own SQL statements (so called **SQL injection**).

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

The error in the SQL statement you have set values inside a quote:

```
VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')
```